# SPContext.Current.Web and security exepction

Tags: web-part, code-access-security

I write a webpart in C# for sharepoint 2007  .When i try to create instance of SPSite or SPWeb , for example:

```
  SPSite sit = new SPSite("http://sharepoint");
```

or

```
 SPSite sit = SPContext.Current.Site;
```

Or even when I :

```
                  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    int t = 0;
                });
```

I get the below security execption :

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' failed.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So...

**Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.**

Change the application's trust level...

> In order to deploy Web Parts that are able to access resources that
>   require a higher trust level, you have three options: Raise the trust
>   level for the entire webapplication, Deploy your Web Parts to the
>   Global Assembly Cache (GAC), or Create your own custom policy.

A quick and dirty way to check if this is the problem:
Open the web.config file and search for a line saying:

```
<trust level="..." />
```

set level to **Full**

Now execute your code again... This should work. Although this is not a good way.

You should deploy your dll's in the GAC or the APP_BIN folder (I prefer the GAC).

Comment: thanks, it worked , but at now I'm on my developing computer and didn't deployed to main sharepoint server , How can I solve it without giving trust level to full?

Comment: Deploy to the GAC, as suggested.

Comment: I depolyed it GAC but without giving trust full the error still exist.

Comment: Did you do an iisreset? (i guess so, just checking). GAC deployment should fix it ...

Comment: How? If I may ask